# jQuery to run after PHP load

Tags: php, jquery

I'm working on a site using the Big Commerce platform. The cart page is built in snippets called by PHP. I don't have access to the PHP files. What I need to do is get the value of a span tag(at a given index) and retrieve the value, I use this value to determine what my minQTY text field should be. I want my code to run after the page has been loaded. However my script isn't working on the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).load(function(){
            $("a.CustomizeItemLink");
            $changeIndex = $("a.CustomizeItemLink").index('a.CustomizeItemLink');
            $change = $("a.CustomizeItemLink").length;
            $productTestArray = ['/american-boxwood-buxus/', '/lavander-crape-myrtle-lagerstroemia-fs/']
            $productLength = $productTestArray.length;

            for(i=0, j=0; i<=$change, j<=$productLength; i++, j++){
            $productTest = "http://www.tnnursery.net"; 
            $productTestValue = $("td.blah a").get(i);                    
            $productTest = "http://www.blah.net" + $productTestArray[j]; 
            $MD = $productTestValue;
            $MS = $productTest;
            $minQTYArray = ['100','100','75','50','25','20','15'];
            $cartSpanValue = $(".productAttributes td span:eq("+i+")").text();            
            $rdTestArray2 = ['6-12','12-18',"1-2'","2-3'","3-4'","4-5'","5-6'"];
            $arr2Test = jQuery.inArray($cartSpanValue, $rdTestArray2);
            $minQTYValue = $minQTYArray[$arr2Test];
            $cartQtyValue = $(".qtyInput:eq("+i+")").val();

            if($MD != $MS){

            }
            else{    
                if($cartQtyValue >= $minQTYValue){

                }
                else{
                    if ($arr2Test == -1){
                    $cartQtyValue = $(".qtyInput:eq(" + i + ")").val('100');    
                    }
                    else{
                    $cartQtyValue = $(".qtyInput:eq(" + i + ")").val($minQTYValue);  
                    alert($cartQtyValue);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    });
});
});
    </script>
```

```
    </td>
    <td class="ProductName" colspan="1">
        <a href="http://www.blah.net/blah-blah-blah/">Item Name1</a><table class="productAttributes" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2">
<tr>
<td>
    <label>Plant&#8203; Size&#8203;s:</label>
</td>
<td>
    <span>12-18&#8203;&quot;</span>
</td>
```

Change
            
                28500
            ()

```
        <div style="display: none" class="WrappingOptions">
            Gift Wrapping:

            <a href="#" onclick="Cart.ManageGiftWrapping('4eea86d587825');" style="">Add</a>
            <span style="display: none">
                (<a href="#" onclick="Cart.ManageGiftWrapping('4eea86d587825');">Change</a> or <a href="cart.php?action=remove_giftwrapping&amp;item_id=4eea86d587825" onclick="return Cart.RemoveGiftWrapping();">Remove</a>)
            </span>
            <br />
            <span style="display: none">
                Gift Message:

            </span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td align="center" class="CartItemQuantity">
        <span style="padding: 0; margin: 0;"><input type="text" size="2" name="qty[4eea86d587825]" id="text_qty_4eea86d587825" class="qtyInput quantityInput" value="50"/></span>

        <div style="">
            <a href="cart.php?action=remove&amp;item=4eea86d587825" onclick="Cart.RemoveItem('4eea86d587825'); return false;" class="CartRemoveLink">Remove</a>
        </div>
    </td>
```

My question is how do I set my jQuery to run after the PHP has been loaded into the page?

Comment: What do you mean? PHP is a server side language, it is "loaded into the page" before jQuery runs by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing `$(document).load` with `$(window).load`.

Comment: Also: just a note. Even if your jQuery statements were the very first lines of your page, all of the PHP on the page would have already been executed. PHP is **preprocessing** that occurs on the server before it even reaches the client's web browser. JavaScript, and therein, jQuery, won't run until the browser encounters them in the DOM. (Of course, all bets are off if there are AJAX calls being made, but in synchronous server interaction, you never have to worry that JavaScript is being executed before PHP is loaded. DOM readiness should be your primary concern there.

Comment: thank you. I had used this but I didnt clean up my code. That was my fault. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should restore the `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Second, the php runs on the server side, and thus before the page itself is loaded. You shouldn't have any worry that your javascript will run before the PHP.

Lastly, I think the reason your code isn't running may be due to syntax errors. If you've copied your code in directly then you have multiple endings to your opening function. I'm not sure if this was intentional or not but you have three sets of closing for the load function when its unnecessary.

Also, this line :

```
$productTestArray = ['/american-boxwood-buxus/', '/lavander-crape-myrtle-lagerstroemia-fs/']
```

Does not have a semi-colon ending the statement. Make these changes and see if your code begins to function properly.

EDIT: Also, in your For loop you define i and j. Why is that? I believe they will always be the same number the way you have it setup. Am I missing something?

Comment: eventually $productTestArray will be much larger than $change. I realized those syntax errors. Would have saved me a few hours of face planting if I would have been more attentive to it. Thanks for the info on PHP

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//your code here

});
```

Comment: I've actually tried that. It was what I originally had. but it did not do anything.