# jQuery centering (outerWidth issue): same code another result

Tags: php, jquery, absolute, outerwidth

In HTML I've created title which I want to center horizontal by using position absolute (because it has to fall over a another element).

I'll use the following code on `document ready`

```
$('.content').find('.title').each( function() {
   var h = $(this).find('h1');
   h.css('marginLeft', -(h.outerWidth()/2));
});
```

While I log the `<h1>` it outputs 232px (in this case), while the real output should be 242px.
The outerWidth is only incorrect at titles executed with the following PHP code:

```
echo (strlen($title) > 20 ? substr($title, 0, 20) . ".." : $title);
```

The same jQuery code as shown above is executed on `window resize`. The result of outerWidth when the browser resizes is also logged and, correct!

So I'll tried to create sort of hack by adding `$(window).resize();` to the `document ready`, but this didn't work.

In [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543279/jquery-to-run-after-php-load) I'll found that to run jQuery after PHP `window load` must be used. But adding `$(window).resize();` or the full jQuery replacing code to the window load are both not working..

Comment: I'm guessing this is an HTML/CSS issue. Do you have a live site to show, or can you reproduce the problem in a JSFiddle?

Comment: I've got a live site. Luxe-beauty.nl/?view=1 and then luxe-beauty.nl/producten. Issue is on the first product.